# MySQL LEFT JOIN - Values can be NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm modifying a MySQL statement but having a few troubles with LEFT JOIN and blank rows. At the moment I have:

```
SELECT cs.case_id, cs.child_firstname, gu.*
FROM tblcases AS cs 
LEFT JOIN tblguardians AS gu
ON cs.case_id = gu.case_id 
WHERE cs.child_firstname = '%craig%' AND gu.firstname LIKE '%sally%'
```

This query works fine as long as there is an entry in the "tblguardians" table, but the LEFT JOIN returns NULL if there is no record - therefore the entry isn't returned when I iterate over the results in PHP.

Is there a way to return the fields from "tblcases" whether or not "tblguardians" has an associated result? I think I've read too many pages of Google for much more information to sink in!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putting a condition on a joined table in your WHERE clause effectively makes that join an INNER JOIN.
To avoid doing that you have to add the second condition to your LEFT JOIN:

```
 SELECT cs.case_id, cs.child_firstname, gu.*
   FROM tblcases cs 

        LEFT JOIN tblguardians gu
        ON cs.case_id = gu.case_id 
    AND gu.firstname LIKE '%sally%' /* <- this line was moved up from WHERE */

  WHERE cs.child_firstname = '%craig%'
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks very much. Modified further to suit my needs but put me on exactly the right track.

Answer (score 4):

You have to restructure your query a little. Putting a condition in the `WHERE` clause will *always remove entire rows*. Since the tblguardians entry can be null because of the `LEFT JOIN`, you can't compare to the `firstname` column in it without removing the entire row.

Since you want results even if there is no match in tblguardians, you will need to move your condition on that table to the `ON` clause in the `JOIN`. That will only remove (set to NULL) the row's result from that table, not the entire row.

```
SELECT cs.case_id, cs.child_firstname, gu.*
FROM tblcases AS cs 
LEFT JOIN tblguardians AS gu
ON cs.case_id = gu.case_id  AND gu.firstname LIKE '%sally%'
WHERE cs.child_firstname = '%craig%'
```

Comment: Equally good answer with the same SQL and posted at the same time. Would be accepted as a second answer if it was possible!

Answer (score 1):

You're filtering on `gu`; if no entries are in the `tblguardians` table, no results will match that `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT JOIN statement permit to show only the results where there are right blank column. If you want to show both blank column, you should to use FULL OUTER JOIN.  So with method you will have left and right blank column.

```
SELECT cs.case_id, cs.child_firstname, gu.*
FROM tblcases AS cs 
FULL OUTER JOIN tblguardians AS gu
ON cs.case_id = gu.case_id 
WHERE cs.child_firstname = '%craig%' AND gu.firstname LIKE '%sally%'
```