# MySQL LEFT JOIN NULL values

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

This question is further to one that was answered back in March 2012. As this is 4 months later I have raised a new question. Reference: [MySQL LEFT JOIN - Values can be NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607767/mysql-left-join-values-can-be-null)

My SQL statement as it stands is below:

```
SELECT cs.case_id, cs.child_firstname, gu.* 
FROM tblcases AS cs 
LEFT JOIN tblguardians AS gu 
ON cs.case_id = gu.case_id AND gu.firstname LIKE '%Craig%'
WHERE cs.child_firstname LIKE '%Sally%'
```

This works fine:

1. If both values are set (per the example above).
2. If cs.child_firstname is set and gu.firstname is a wildcard only

However, if cs.child_firstname is a wildcard only and gu.firstname is set then all rows in the database are returned, including NULL values - ideally in that situation I don't want the NULL values.

Can this query be rewritten to do everything or do I need to have more than 1 query?

**Update**

The fields below are the fields in my form, all are passed using $_POST and processed using PHP. I hope this gives some indication of where the data is coming from and how it relates to the database tables. Child fields are in tblcases and guardian fields in tblguardians.

- Child Firstname
- Child Lastname
- Child Date of Birth
- Guardian Firstname
- Guardian Lastname
- Guardian Phone
- Guardian Postcode

**Update 2**

SQL query is now as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(cs.case_id) AS case_id, CONCAT(cs.child_firstname, ' ', child_surname) AS childname, DATE_FORMAT(child_dob, '%d/%m/%Y') AS child_dob, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d/%m/%Y') AS created, gu.firstname, gu.surname
FROM 
    tblcases AS cs 
LEFT JOIN tblguardians AS gu 
    ON cs.case_id = gu.case_id 
    AND gu.firstname LIKE '%$_POST[parent_firstname]%'
    AND gu.surname LIKE '%$_POST[parent_lastname]%'
WHERE 
cs.child_firstname LIKE '%$_POST[child_firstname]%' 
AND cs.child_surname LIKE '%$_POST[child_surname]%'
AND ('$_POST[child_firstname]' != '' OR gu.firstname IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Are you populating the `LIKE` values from code?

Comment: if you want to replace the null values use IFNULL(column , defaultvalue) or if you want to avoid the whole record then use inner join instead of left join

Comment: @Michael - Yes, like this: '%$_POST[child_firstname]%'

ruakh - I mean if the $_POST value is empty when the form is submitted, the SQL query will be wildcard-only (ie. gu.firstname LIKE '%%')

Comment: @raheelshan - INNER JOIN works for removing the NULL values, however I need those NULL values because there won't always be a corresponding record in the tblguardians table. If a case is created, but no guardians added to it, I still need to be able to search based on the case details. If a case has guardians added to it, I need to be able to search on the contents of the guardians table without entering the child firstname or lastname stored in the tblcases table..

Comment: as you state you ARE adding the values directly from a post, you are WIDE OPEN to SQL-Injection... you should look into cleaning your input.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the ideal solution would be a "full join" - returns all rows from both tables and then you would use the where clause to eliminate where "both sides are null" - e.g. ifnull( gu.firstname, cs.child_firstname) is not null

Mysql does not support full joins so then your best option would be a union something like

```
select blah
from tblcases 
join tblguardians on blah
where tblcases.child_firstname like childINPUT

union

select blah -- same blah as aobve
from tblcases 
join tblguardians on blah
where tblguardians.firstname like guardianINPUT
```