# Remove LEFT JOIN null value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way which can remove LEFT JOIN's null value insertion if there is no value present in table in mysql? Can we replace it with other thing, such as '' or "not available" texts? I tried COALESCE and IFNULL, still, no victory...

my query is:

```
SELECT r.*,GROUP_CONCAT(ri.image_name SEPARATOR ',') total_images 
FROM recipe as r 
LEFT JOIN recipe_images ri on r.recipe_id=ri.recipe_id 
WHERE r.recipe_id = 107
```

here the query should return empty instead of null in comma separated values if no images exist. Is it possible?

The output i am getting right now in total_images is:
`null, abc. jpg, ghi, jpg`

i want to remove `null`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607767/mysql-left-join-values-can-be-null please refer this

Comment: `group_concat(coalesce(ri.image_name, '')  separator ',')` should really do it

Comment: How is your syntax and what happens when you use coalesce?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE` like this `GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(ri.image_name, '') SEPARATOR ',')`

```
SELECT r.*, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(ri.image_name,'') SEPARATOR ',') total_images 
FROM recipe as r
    LEFT JOIN recipe_images ri on r.recipe_id = ri.recipe_id
WHERE r.recipe_id = 107
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your quick response.But your query returns NULL value as result in all columns.I need only in total_images where there is null.

Comment: can you add your sample data and the output of the query to your question.